# Why the mocha process hangs if require lzutf8

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, mocha.js

If my code require the lzutf8 module.
Then all mocha cases show passed but the process actually hang.

Code:

`const LZUTF8 = require("lzutf8");`

Mocha result:

```
   ......
   √ 6 - Check result  (1278ms)

  6 passing (9s)
```

If remove the require, the process could end successfully.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.